# python truncate after a hundreds?

Tags: python, truncate

How can truncate an input like 315.15321531321
I want to truncate all the values after the hundredths position so it becomes 315.15

how do i do that?

Comment: You might also want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/python-limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points/455634#455634

Comment: Rex, I liked the answer at the question you quoted so much, I just upvoted it; you did a great job explaining the connections between int, float and Decimal in Python.

Answer (score 14):

String formatting under python 2.x should do it for you:

```
>>> print '%.2f' % 315.15321531321
315.15
```

This limits the string representation to just 2 decimal places. Note that if you use `round(315.153215, 2)`, you'll end up with another float value, which is naturally imprecise (or overprecise, depending on how you look at it):

```
>>> round(315.15321531321, 2)
315.14999999999998
```

Technically, `round()` is correct, but it doesn't "truncate" the results as you requested at `315.15`. In addition, if you round a value like 315.157, it will produce something closer to 315.16... not sure if that's what you mean by "truncate".

Comment: Interestingly, I read yesterday that Python 3.1rc1 now chooses the shortest string representation that resolves to the same floating point number, so your second example with round() would print 315.15 as expected: http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/whatsnew/3.1.html#other-language-changes

Comment: Thank you, Greg - I didn't know that. Good additional info; the more I hear about py3k, the more I can't wait to use it day-to-day!

Answer (score 9):

Looks like print "%.2f" does rounding as well.
Here is Python code that rounds and truncates

```
num = 315.15627
print("rounded   = %.2f" % num)
print("truncated = %.2f" % (int(num*100)/float(100)))

print(f'rounded   = {num:.2f}')
print(f'truncated = {int(num*100)/float(100):.2f}')

**Outputs**
rounded   = 315.16
truncated = 315.15
rounded   = 315.16
truncated = 315.15
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're working with currency amounts, I strongly recommend that you use Python's decimal class instead: http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to display it shortened, you can use the `"%f"` formating flag:

```
value = 315.123123123
print "Value is: %.2f" % value
```

If you want to really cut off the "additional" digits, do something like:

```
from math import trunc
value = trunc(value*100)/100
```

Comment: You should multiply by 100 inside the parentheses and divide after truncating, otherwise you only get 300 back.

Comment: And then there's the builtin round()…

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you:

```
a=315.15321531321
a=a*100
a=int(a)
a=a/100.0
print(a)
315.15
```

Explanation: If you want to round at the second decimal place then you should:
1. multiply your number by 100; this gives you 31515.321531321,
2. convert this new number to integer; int(31515.321531321) gives you 31515,
3. divide this by 100.0; 31515/100.0,
4. and you get the correct answer; **315.15**

Enjoy!

Comment: Your answer certainly is worth a little explanation. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .

Answer (score 1):

You have several options - you can round the number using round(), however this can introduce some inaccuracies (315.15 might round to 315.150000003 for example). If you're just looking to truncate the value of the float when you're displaying it, you can specify the width of the output using printf("%.2f", mynumber).  This is probably a better solution, since without knowing more about your specific application it's a good idea in general to keep the entire length of the number for calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in function `round()`:

```
>>> num = 315.1532153132
>>> round(num, 2)
3.1499999999999998
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with `Decimal` types and currency, where the amount needs to be precise, here is what I came up with for truncating to cents (hundredths):

```
amount = Decimal(long(amount * 100)) / Decimal(100)
```

**A little history**: I tried `quantize` but it tends to round rather than truncate. And I couldn't in good conscience use expensive string formatters for something so simple. And finally I didn't want any precision problems a la `float` so I use very specific casting that is probably overkill.